# Injecting an Angular service into an integration test

Tags: angularjs, testing

A constructor function accepts AngularJS's `$q` as an argument.

How do I get hold of an instance of `$q` for the purposes of instantiating the constructor function outside of the context of the normal running of the angular application (i.e. in an integration test)?

```
function MtCtorFunction($q) {
  //...
}
```

Comment: You have to use inject function.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your tests:

```
beforeEach(inject(function($q){

}));
```

Thanks.